# Looping parse json error in angularjs

Tags: android, angularjs, json

I build android apk and install apk in android lolipop adn application work correctly but if application install to android kitkat it doesn't work and just show splashscreen after it just white blank in interface.
I know the trouble in parse json but i don't know how to fix it
this my parse json

```
kaka.cari($scope.item.code).success(function(data){
                  $scope.result1= data;
                  var lat0 = parseFloat(data[0].latitude);
                  var lng0 = parseFloat(data[0].longitude);
              var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 15,
                center: {lat: lat0, lng: lng0},
                mapTypeId: 'terrain'
              });
              var flightPlanCoordinates = data.map((item)=>{
                    // create new object based on current item
                    var coords = {
                       lat: parseFloat(item.latitude),
                       lng: parseFloat(item.longitude)
                    };
                    // return to new array
                    return coords;
              });
              var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2
              });
              flightPath.setMap(map);
              })
              .error(function(data){
              });
           };
```

if i don't use `var flightPlanCoordinates` and try hardcode lat and long it work but if i use `var flightPlanCoordinates` will be error in android kitkat but not error in `ionic serve`
This my json

```
[{"latitude":"-7.331069","longitude":"112.764192"},{"latitude":"-7.331277","longitude":"112.764198"},{"latitude":"-7.331467","longitude":"112.764186"},{"latitude":"-7.331659","longitude":"112.764159"},{"latitude":"-7.331840","longitude":"112.764154"},{"latitude":"-7.332016","longitude":"112.764133"},{"latitude":"-7.332192","longitude":"112.764112"},{"latitude":"-7.332400","longitude":"112.764101"},{"latitude":"-7.332592","longitude":"112.764074"},{"latitude":"-7.332789","longitude":"112.764074"},{"latitude":"-7.333018","longitude":"112.764047"},{"latitude":"-7.333236","longitude":"112.764042"},{"latitude":"-7.333465","longitude":"112.763994"},{"latitude":"-7.333662","longitude":"112.763956"},{"latitude":"-7.333843","longitude":"112.763838"},{"latitude":"-7.333965","longitude":"112.763704"},{"latitude":"-7.333933","longitude":"112.763747"},{"latitude":"-7.334034","longitude":"112.763608"},{"latitude":"-7.333981","longitude":"112.763297"},{"latitude":"-7.333917","longitude":"112.763018"},{"latitude":"-7.333901","longitude":"112.762723"},{"latitude":"-7.333869","longitude":"112.762444"},{"latitude":"-7.333832","longitude":"112.762127"},{"latitude":"-7.333800","longitude":"112.761730"},{"latitude":"-7.333768","longitude":"112.761473"}]
```

this data console.log(flightPlanCoordinates)

```
0:Object
 lat:-7.331069
 lng:112.764192
1:Object
2:Object
3:Object
4:Object
5:Object
6:Object
7:Object
8:Object
9:Object
10:Object
11:Object
12:Object
13:Object
14:Object
15:Object
16:Object
17:Object
18:Object
19:Object
20:Object
21:Object
22:Object
23:Object
24:Object
```

please help me solve my problem

Comment: can you share what `console.log(flightPlanCoordinates)` produces ?

Comment: yeah, i already edit my question and i write to console.log

Comment: Do you get any error or exception in Logcat?

Comment: if i run ionic serve show 2 error and 1 exception, first GET http://192.168.1.152:8100/lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js 
ionic.bundle.js:43929 WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once. Second http://192.168.1.152:8100/lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js 404 (Not Found). And ecxeption Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required